Openai Issue, trying te generated Speech but always getting error
I am working on a app that can describe data into narration and then convert it into audio by using openai
but always facing error while it creating the audio file, don't know where i am lacking
Narrater.py
import openai



def parse(narration):
    output = []
    lines = narration.split("/n")
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Background: '):
            background = line.replace("Background:","Background: ")
            output.append({
                "type":"image",
                "description":background
            })

        elif line.startswith("Narration:"):
            text = line.replace("Narration:","Narration:")
            output.append({
                "type":"text",
                "content":text
            })
    return output


def create(data,output_path="output_audio.mp3"):
    narration = ""  # Initialize the narration variable as an empty string
    for element in data:
        if element["type"] != 'text':
            continue
        narration += element["content"] + "\n\n"
    audio = openai.audio.speech.create(
        model="tts-1",
        input = narration,
        voice="alloy"
    )
    audio.stream_to_file(output_path)

transcripter.py




# Read the source material from a file
with open("source_material.txt", "r") as f:
    source_material = f.read()

# Create the chat completion
response = openai.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "system", 
            "content": """You are a short Video Narratorthat reads the data and explains 
            it. You generate 30S TO 1 minutes of narration. 
            The short you create has a background that fades from image to image as the narration is going on.

            Respond in the following manner, repeating until the end of the short:
            Background: Description of background image based on the narration for AI Image Generation and also add the data 
            Narration: A few sentences of narration based on the data in detail  
            
            Background: Description of background image based on the narration for AI Image Generation with data and also add the data 
            Narration: A few sentences of narration based on the data in detail 

            Background: Description of background image based on the narration for AI Image Generation with data and also add the data  
            Narration: A few sentences of narration based on the data in detail

            Background: Description of background image based on the narration for AI Image Generation with data and also add the data 
            Narration: A few sentences of narration based on the data in detail

            Background: Description of background image based on the narration for AI Image Generation with data and also add the data 
            Narration: A few sentences of narration based on the data in detail


            The short MUST be 6 sentences maximum.
            """
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": f"Create a short video narrator based on the following source material:\n\n{source_material}"
        }
    ]
)

# Extract the generated content from the response
generated_content = response.choices[0].message.content

# Print the generated content
data = narrator.parse(generated_content)
print(data)
audio = narrator.create(data, "narration.mp3")

(myenv) PS D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\DataTOVideo> python .\Transcripter.py
[{'type': 'image', 'description': "Background:  A dynamic and modern digital marketing office space with screens showing colorful graphs and charts related to advertising performance data.\nNarration: Analyzing the ad campaign performance data reveals a steady increase in impressions, clicks, and conversions over the course of five days. Costs also rise as the campaign expands, but so does revenue, indicating a positive return on investment.\n\nBackground:  A sleek data analysis room with futuristic holographic displays showcasing various calculated metrics.\nNarration: By diving into the calculated metrics, we can see that the click-through rate remains relatively stable around 1.5%, while the cost per click fluctuates slightly. The conversion rate shows an upward trend, peaking on the third day, leading to a consistent return on ad spend (ROAS) above 2.00.\n\nBackground:  An innovative marketing agency setting with screens displaying detailed performance breakdowns and key metrics.\nNarration: Through a closer examination of the data, it's evident that the ad campaign is performing well overall, with a healthy balance between cost-efficiency and conversion optimization. The trends indicate potential areas for further optimization to maximize results and drive even higher ROAS.\n\nBackground:  A futuristic control center environment with real-time updates on ad campaign performance metrics.\nNarration: The ad campaign's success is reflected in the calculated metrics, showcasing a solid click-through rate alongside a cost per click that remains competitive. With conversion rates on the rise and a stable ROAS above 2.00, the data highlights a well-executed and profitable advertising strategy.\n\nBackground:  A high-tech data visualization room with interactive screens illustrating the impact of various advertising strategies.\nNarration: Overall, the ad campaign's performance data and calculated metrics paint a picture of a well-managed and effective marketing initiative. The consistent growth in key metrics, paired with a positive return on ad spend, underscores the success of the campaign in driving both engagement and revenue for the business."}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\DataTOVideo\Transcripter.py", line 56, in 
audio = narrator.create(data, "narration.mp3")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\DataTOVideo\narrator.py", line 42, in create
audio = openai.audio.speech.create(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\audio\speech.py", line 96, in create
return self._post(
stream_cls=stream_cls))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\Lib\site-packages\openai_base_client.py", line 957, in request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\Lib\site-packages\openai_base_client.py", line 1061, in _request
raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "[{'type': 'string_too_short', 'loc': ('body', 'input'), 'msg': 'String should have at least 1 character', 'input': '',
'ctx': {'min_length': 1}}]", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}
(myenv) PS D:\Python Data To Video\AppTest\Transcripter\myenv\DataTOVideo>
I tried to downgrade the openai but it didn't work therefore i went to default

based on the error, it seems you passed an empty string, Can you validate if the narration is empty or not before you fire your openai request?

also there is a typo in parse: /n should be \n
